# pip install json2html in python 3.5 not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have python 3.5 and 2.7 installed, I only use python 3.4.

When trying to install pip install json2html, it generates the error:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: json2html in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (1.3.0)
```

How do I install json2html on python 3?

See the directories:
$ ls /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

> certifi chardet-3.0.4.dist-info  graphyte.pyc json2html
> pip-20.3.4.dist-info urllib3 certifi-2017.11.5.dist-info
> graphyte-1.4.dist-info idna json2html-1.3.0.dist-info requests
> urllib3-1.22.dist-info chardet graphyte.py idna-2.6.dist-info pip
> requests-2.18.4.dist-info

$ ls /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/

> certifi certifi-2018.1.18.dist-info chardet chardet-3.0.4.dist-info
> idna idna-2.6.dist-info requests requests-2.18.4.dist-info urllib3
> urllib3-1.22.dist-info

$ pip freeze

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
asn1crypto==0.22.0
attrs==15.2.0
beautifulsoup4==4.4.1
carbon==0.9.15
certifi==2017.11.5
chardet==3.0.4
cryptography==1.9
Django==1.8.7
django-tagging==0.4
enum34==1.1.2
graphite-web==0.9.15
graphyte==1.4
html5lib==0.999
idna==2.6
ipaddress==1.0.17
json2html==1.3.0
lxml==3.5.0
meld3==1.0.2
mysqlclient==1.3.7
PAM==0.4.2
pyasn1==0.1.9
pyasn1-modules==0.0.7
PyMySQL==0.9.3
pyOpenSSL==17.3.0
pyparsing==2.0.3
pyserial==3.0.1
pytz==2014.10
requests==2.18.4
service-identity==16.0.0
simplejson==3.8.1
six==1.11.0
sqlparse==0.1.18
supervisor==3.2.0
Twisted==16.0.0
urllib3==1.22
whisper==0.9.15
zope.interface==4.3.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried installing it by specifying the python version?
`python3.4 -m pip install SomePackage`
See [this](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html).